# Typing the location.state property on a component basis using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I have the idea to define of what type the `location.state` for a certain stateless component can be.
I found a few articles that build on the `RouteComponentProps` type but I could not figure out the details.

Assume in this example, that I expect the `location.state` property to be of type

```
type StateType = {
    id: number,
    type: number
}
```

or let type` even be an enumeration. Can this be implemented?

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
const Index = ({ location, history }) => {
    return (
        <div>Test</div>
    )
}

export default withRouter(Index)
```

Answer (score 7):

Type `RouteComponentProps` of `react-router` is a generic type. This is how you can define location state with your custom type (I modified your example):

```js
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

type StateType = {
    id: number,
    type: number
}

type IndexProps = RouteComponentProps<{}, {}, StateType>;

const Index: React.FC<IndexProps> = ({ location, history }) => {
    return (
        <div>{location.state && (
            <ul>
                <li>{location.state.id}</li>
                <li>{location.state.type}</li>
            </ul>
        )}</div>
    );
}

export default withRouter(Index);
```

Some takeaways:

- you should probably always check whether `location.state` is defined, it may happen that state is not passed for whatever reason
- we had to add correct type to the component itself via `React.FC` generic type (though, there are other ways to do that...)
- [`RouteComponentProps`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-router/index.d.ts#L70) actually gets three types to be properly defined:

  - first (empty `{}` in my example) - type of [`<Route />`'s parameters](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string-string)
  - second (empty `{}` in my example) - type of the [`<StaticRouter />`'s context](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/StaticRouter/context-object)
  - and finally, third (`StateType` in my example) - type of the location's state
- `location` object can be found also in `history.location`, but it's not typed and should *not* be used, as [stated in documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history/history-is-mutable):

  > ... The history object is mutable. Therefore it is recommended to access the location from the render props of `<Route>`, not from `history.location`. ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use generic type `Location` and simply extend it with `StateType`.

```
import { Location } from 'history';

type LocationProps = Location<StateType>;
```

Remember to type your component properly:

```
interface IndexProps {
   location: LocationProps;
   classes: // your type
   history: // your type
}

const Index = ({ classes, location, history }: IndexProps) => {
```

Comment: So this way I have to define history as well. It cannot be left blank to the default types are used?

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer Just try to leave it blank. If tsc won't blame then its fine. If not, you will probably have to type History also :)